# Frost free stem assembly replacement issues

Tags: plumbing, exterior

I'm attempting to replace the stem assembly on a Arrowhead Brass frost free hose bibb. When trying to screw the new assembly into the fixture, the threads on the new stem catch briefly on the old faucet, but pop back out if I attempt to screw it in further. The threads on the original faucet are corroded. Is there a way I can address this myself, or is this a situation where we summon the pros?

[Frost Free Fun: The Album](https://imgur.com/a/Hf5CzlO)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears from your pictures that you need to back the valve stem off through the packing nut (open it, so the actual valve at the other end of the stem is not conflicting with trying to get the packing nut  screwed in.) Don't tighten/close the new valve until the packing nut is secured. Either that, or you have a stem of the wrong length, but that seems the most likely reason for it to be "close, but not quite." Particularly given how little of the new valve stem is showing outside the packing nut in your pictures.

The corrosion on the valve body threads is trivial and not a factor.